# send variables to controller('resolve') in ngDialog

Tags: angularjs, ng-dialog

Simple way of opening modal with ngDialog is this:

```
ngDialog.open({
    template: 'template.html',
    controller: 'someCtrl'
})
```

How can I send variables to that 'someCtrl'?

Is there such thing as 'resolve' in ngDialog?

**Example from angular-bootstrap modal:**

```
$modal.open({
    template: "<p>This is template</p>",
    controller: "someCtrl",
    resolve: {
        someVar: function(){
            return "Value of someVar"
        }
    }
})
```

this would open the modal send the 'someVar' to the responsible Controller.

**UPDATE:**

It seems like new version of ngDialog added this feature:

```
ngDialog.open({
    controller: function Ctrl(dep) {/*...*/},
    resolve: {
        dep: function depFactory() {
            return 'dep value';
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well looks like ngDialog doesn't support resolve and custom injection in controller. However you can alway do it manually by creating `controller` instance yourself:

```
ngDialog.open({
    scope: $scope,
    template: 'template.html',
    controller: $controller('someCtrl', {
        $scope: $scope,
        name: 'Thomas'
    })
});
```

then in controller you will be able to access injected service/variable:

```
app.controller('someCtrl', function($scope, name) {
    console.log(name); // Thomas
});
```

However there is a caveat with this approach, because when controller in instantiated by `ngDialog` itself it also injects [`$element`](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog/blob/master/js/ngDialog.js#L222) service in it, which is an `angular.element` instance of the opened dialog HTML (however I doubt it's even necessary in controller). But you should know it anyway.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/3YpQ2bemk8fntKAPWY9i?p=preview

Comment: help needed!!! As you said, it sends the variable to the controller and in the controller I assign it to $scope.variable. But that controller has stopped being responsible for the template :( $scope.variable cannot be seen in the template(like: {{name}})

Comment: Check updated demo, you also need to pass `scope: $scope` for this approach. If you don't specify `scope` option `ngDialog` creates child scope of the `$rootScope` and compile template in this scope. However in `someCtrl` you are dealing with child scope of the `$scope` passed in during `$controller` instantiation.

Comment: your demo is perfectly working as I want. But it the same thing is not working for me. Maybe because of the angular or ngDialog versions

Comment: Make sure you open dialog with `scope: $scope,` options and use the same `$scope` for `$controller('someCtrl', {$scope: $scope})`.

Comment: Ok, now it is working! I misunderstood what you said by scope: $scope, as there were two such lines. Now it is fixed! THank you :)