# How do I access the properties in the scope of an ng-repeated item inside of an ng-dialog specific to each item?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-dialog

So I have a list of ng-repeated items, and each of these items has it's own button that calls a popup that I create using ng-dialog.  I need to print the properties of the item in each pop up.

html:

```
<button ng-click="clickToOrder()">order</button>
```

controller:

```
    $scope.clickToOrder = function (dish) {
    var newScope = $scope;
    newScope.dish = dish;
    ngDialog.open({
      template: '{{dish.time}}',
      plain: true,
      scope: newScope
     });
};
```

So I am repeating through "dishes" and these dishes have the property "time" that I want to print out in the popup.  The popup shows up but the properties in the scope associated to "dish" do not get sent to the popup.  Any way to send the specific properties for each dish in ng-repeat to the ng-dialog popup?

Comment: you aren't passing the `dish` into the function.  it should be `ng-click="clickToOrder(dish)"` or something similar.  also, that `var newScope = $scope` seems odd, and may not act quite the way you expect;  I don't know if that's part of the syntax for `nDialog` or what, but it's definitely a leaky abstraction.

Comment: ^Savior!  That was it I forgot to pass dish in the html

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
ngDialog.open({
    controller: function Ctrl(dep) {/*...*/},
    resolve: {
        dish: function getDish() {
            return dish;
        }
    }
});
```

[send variables to controller('resolve') in ngDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27920637/send-variables-to-controllerresolve-in-ngdialog)